# Serial Port unauthorized access exception

Tags: c#, io

I'm trying to read in some information from a serial port, but when I actually to open a connnection it throws a  unauthorized access exception

This code reads in the port names

```
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
        string[] serialPorts = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();


        public Page_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < serialPorts.Count(); i++)
                portBox.Items.Add(serialPorts[i]);
        }
```

This is the code which tries to the the information coming from the serial port

```
            port.PortName = portBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            port.Open();// This is where the exception is thrown

            serialOutput.Text = port.ReadLine();
```

Comment: what is the value of port.PortName?

Comment: So, the man page for SerialPort.Open() says - access denied to port OR a process already has the specified COM port open

Comment: This will happen if the port is already open with another program.

Comment: Well it is a USB to Serial cable so that may be the problem

Comment: USB to serial shouldn't be a problem, are you sure COM3 comes on that device?

Comment: No it didn't have an affect at all, simply closed the other program using the port and the exception went away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access is denied to the port.

- or -

The current process, or another process on the system, already has the specified COM port open either by a SerialPort instance or in unmanaged code.